# Pegar Valor Booleano Coluna GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho um `GridView` preenchendo corretamente, porém necessito pegar o valor da coluna 5, que é do tipo `BIT` no banco de dados (SQL Server).

De todas as formas que tento, informa erro, já tentei passar pra uma variável do tipo `bool`, passar para um `CheckBox` e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Segue o código:

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     txtid.Text = (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
     conta = (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
     bool Insertar = ((CheckBox)(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].FindControl("quitado"))).Checked;
     if (Insertar == true)
     {
         cbquitado.Checked = true;
     }
}
```

Tentei assim também:

```
bool quitado = Convert.ToBoolean(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text);
```

Como eu consigo pegar o valor da coluna, ao selecionar a linha no `GridView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desta forma (atualizado):

```
CheckBox Insertar = (CheckBox)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Controls[0];
if(Insertar.Checked == true)
{
     //seu código
}
```

Atribuí direto ao cbquitado, mas, poderá fazer do seu jeito:

```
if(Insertar.Checked == true)
{
    cbquitado.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Tentei dessa Forma Ismael, e me ocorreu erro nessa linha: cbquitado.Checked = Insertar.Checked; 
Erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Eu já estava editando a resposta dizendo para você verificar primeiro se o `SelectedRow` está ou não *null*. Esta propriedade só é válida para quando clicar pelo menos em alguma linha. Ela inicia como null.

Comment: rsrs 
eu mostro o campo em uma mensagem, porém ele vem null, só q com um campo normal do tipo string no mesmo comando, aparece normal.

Comment: No seu gridview ele não é do tipo CheckBoxField?

Comment: Exato. 
     <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="quitado" HeaderText="Quitado">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:CheckBoxField>
Tentei dessa forma q me informou, e o me mostra o mesmo erro na linha: cbquitado.Checked = Insertar.Checked.
Erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Consegui resolver Ismael realizando um select através do ID que eu consigo pegar normalmente, e resolveu o problema, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu criei um formulario e coloquei nele um dataGridView, com dois campos(celula1 e celua2) 
Mais dois checkBox e um botão
cliquei no dataGridView1 e depoi em propriedades e procurei pelo evento click, e depois um duplo qlique pra gera o evento.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "true";
        DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "false";
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["celula1"].Value.ToString());
        checkBox2.Checked = Boolean.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["celula2"].Value.ToString());

    }
}
}
```